# dropdown with Javascript options HTML required element

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with one of the dropdowns mainly the passenger dropdown.
The cars and passenger elements both have Javascript actions attached, cars calculates total cost, which works perfectly and has the required tag, which again works perfectly if nothing is selected. Passenger changes on what is selected from the cars, again that works perfectly but, the require tag doesn't work, I been banging my head on the wall so much, frankly, I think I've got a fractured skull! :-( Where have I gone wrong? Can anybody help please?

```js
     let passengers = {
        "1": [{
                value: 0,
          desc: ""
        }, {
          value: 1,
          desc: "1 Passenger"
        }, {
          value: 2,
          desc: "2 Passengers"
        }, {
          value: 3,
          desc: "3 Passengers"
          }, {
          value: 4,
          desc: "4 Passengers"
        }, {
          value: 5,
          desc: "5 Passengers"
        }],
        "2": [{
        
          desc: ""
        }, {            
          value: 1,
          desc: "1 Passenger"
        }, {
          value: 2,
          desc: "2 Passengers"
        }, {
          value: 3,
          desc: "3 Passengers"
          }, {
          value: 4,
          desc: "4 Passengers"
        }, {
          value: 5,
          desc: "5 Passengers"
        }, {
          value: 6,
          desc: "6 Passengers"
          }, {
          value: 7,
          desc: "7 Passengers"
        }, {
          value: 8,
          desc: "8 Passengers"
        }, {
          value: 9,
          desc: "9 Passengers"
          }, {
          value: 10,
          desc: "10 Passengers"       
        }],
        "3": [{
        
          desc: ""
        }, {            
          value: 1,
          desc: "1 Passenger"
        }, {
          value: 2,
          desc: "2 Passengers"
        }, {
          value: 3,
          desc: "3 Passengers"
          }, {
          value: 4,
          desc: "4 Passengers"
        }, {
          value: 5,
          desc: "5 Passengers"
        }, {
          value: 6,
          desc: "6 Passengers"
          }, {
          value: 7,
          desc: "7 Passengers"
        }, {
          value: 8,
          desc: "8 Passengers"
        }, {
          value: 9,
          desc: "9 Passengers"
          }, {
          value: 10,
          desc: "10 Passengers"
        }, {
          value: 11,
          desc: "11 Passengers"
        }, {
          value: 12,
          desc: "12 Passengers"
          }, {
          value: 13,
          desc: "13 Passengers"
        }, {
          value: 14,
          desc: "14 Passengers"
        }, {
          value: 15,
          desc: "15 Passengers"       
        }],
      }

      document.getElementsByName('cars')[0].addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        document.getElementsByName('passenger')[0].innerHTML = passengers[this.value].reduce((acc, elem) => `${acc}<option value="${elem.value}">${elem.desc}</option>`, "");
      });

    function totalise() {
     var qtd = document.getElementById('cars').value;
     var price = document.getElementById('cost').value;
     var result = document.getElementById('total');
     result.value = price * qtd;
     }
```

```html
 <input type="hidden" name="cost" id="cost" value="50">
<form action="" method="POST">
<div>
<select required="required" name="cars" id="cars" onChange="totalise()">
<option></option>
<option value="1">1 Car</option>
<option value="2">2 Cars</option>
<option value="3">3 Cars</option>
</select>
                          
</div>
<div>
<select required="required" name="passenger" id="passenger">
<option></option>
</select>
</div>
<input type="text" id="total" size="4" readonly>
<div>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Because it has the value `0`. `required` pretty much checks for empty string and not falsy.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your Array like this, like SimonU said required checks empty strings.

> The required attribute is a boolean attribute.
>
> When present, it specifies that an input field must be filled out
> before submitting the form.
>
> Note: The required attribute works with the following input types:
> text, search, url, tel, email, password, date pickers, number,
> checkbox, radio, and file.
> [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp)

```js
let passengers = {
  "1": [{
          value:"",
          desc: ""
        }, {
          value: 1,
          desc: "1 Passenger"
        }, {
          value: 2,
          desc: "2 Passengers"
        }, {
          value: 3,
          desc: "3 Passengers"
          }, {
          value: 4,
          desc: "4 Passengers"
        }, {
          value: 5,
          desc: "5 Passengers"
        }],
        "2": [{
          value:"",
          desc: ""
        }, {            
          value: 1,
          desc: "1 Passenger"
        }, {
          value: 2,
          desc: "2 Passengers"
        }, {
          value: 3,
          desc: "3 Passengers"
          }, {
          value: 4,
          desc: "4 Passengers"
        }, {
          value: 5,
          desc: "5 Passengers"
        }, {
          value: 6,
          desc: "6 Passengers"
          }, {
          value: 7,
          desc: "7 Passengers"
        }, {
          value: 8,
          desc: "8 Passengers"
        }, {
          value: 9,
          desc: "9 Passengers"
          }, {
          value: 10,
          desc: "10 Passengers"       
        }],
        "3": [{
          value:"",
          desc: ""
        }, {            
          value: 1,
          desc: "1 Passenger"
        }, {
          value: 2,
          desc: "2 Passengers"
        }, {
          value: 3,
          desc: "3 Passengers"
          }, {
          value: 4,
          desc: "4 Passengers"
        }, {
          value: 5,
          desc: "5 Passengers"
        }, {
          value: 6,
          desc: "6 Passengers"
          }, {
          value: 7,
          desc: "7 Passengers"
        }, {
          value: 8,
          desc: "8 Passengers"
        }, {
          value: 9,
          desc: "9 Passengers"
          }, {
          value: 10,
          desc: "10 Passengers"
        }, {
          value: 11,
          desc: "11 Passengers"
        }, {
          value: 12,
          desc: "12 Passengers"
          }, {
          value: 13,
          desc: "13 Passengers"
        }, {
          value: 14,
          desc: "14 Passengers"
        }, {
          value: 15,
          desc: "15 Passengers"       
        }],
      }

      document.getElementsByName('cars')[0].addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        document.getElementsByName('passenger')[0].innerHTML = passengers[this.value].reduce((acc, elem) => `${acc}<option value="${elem.value}">${elem.desc}</option>`, "");
      });

    function totalise() {
     var qtd = document.getElementById('cars').value;
     var price = document.getElementById('cost').value;
     var result = document.getElementById('total');
     result.value = price * qtd;
     }
```

```html
<input type="hidden" name="cost" id="cost" value="50">
<form action="" method="POST">
<div>
<select required="required" name="cars" id="cars" onChange="totalise()">
<option></option>
<option value="1">1 Car</option>
<option value="2">2 Cars</option>
<option value="3">3 Cars</option>
</select>
                          
</div>
<div>
<select required="required" name="passenger" id="passenger">
<option></option>
</select>
</div>
<input type="text" id="total" size="4" readonly>
<div>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: I think I had been looking at this far, far, far too long, it was so obvious what was missing, completely blinded. Many thanks.